# How do I express $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^{2m-1}\left(t\right)\cos^{2n-1}(t)dt$ using the Gamma-function?

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, gamma-function

We define the Gamma function as: $$\Gamma(p)=\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-x}x^{p-1}dx$$

I was advised to rewrite the integral as $\sin(t)^{2m-1}\cos(t)^{2n-2} d \sin(t)$, and substitute $ t = \sin(t)$ which brings me to :

$$\int_0^1t^{2m-1}\left(1-t^2\right)^{n-1}dt$$

But I don't know how to go on from there.

Comment: you can express it in terms of beta function $\beta(m,n)=\frac{\Gamma(m)\Gamma(n)}{\Gamma(m+n)}$

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BetaFunction.html

Comment: So I can say $$q = t^2; dt = \frac{dq}{2t}$$$$\implies \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1q^{m-1}(1-q)^{n-1}dq$$ ? and then express it as a function of $\frac{1}{2}\beta(m,n)$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $~e^{-x}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\bigg(1-\dfrac xn\bigg)^n~:~$ Use this well-known identity, along with a simple

substitution, to bridge the gap between the integral expressions of the two functions.

Answer (score 0):

The Gamma function is $\Gamma (s)=\int_0^\infty x^{s-1}e^{-x}dx=2\int_0^\infty x^{2s-1}e^{-x^2}dx$. Thus $$\Gamma (m)\Gamma (n)=2\int_{[0,\,\infty)^2}(r\cos\theta)^{2m-1}(r\sin\theta)^{2n-1}e^{-r^2}rdrd\theta=2\Gamma(m+n)I,$$where your integral is $$I=\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^{2m-1}\theta\cos^{2n-1}\theta d\theta=\frac{\Gamma (m)\Gamma (n)}{2\Gamma (m+n)}.$$